# Substring Replacement in Batch Files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Currently I'm trying to create a program that will perform different functions depending on the input.

I'm using the set command to get input from the user and an if statement to test if the user is asking the right question. These work fine, but when I try to get rid of 'where' and 'is', it says I haven't defined the environment variables.

```
set /p input=-
if not "%input:where=%"=="%input%" if not "%input:is=%"=="%input%"
set %input:where=%
set %input:is=%
start www.google.com/maps/place/%input%
```

Basically I'm trying to make it so that the only thing left in 'input' is the location. For example, if the user puts in, 'where is paris' the only thing left will be 'paris' which will then be searched for by google maps.
I used the set /? command for help and I'm pretty sure the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set INPUT=%input:where=%
set INPUT=%input:is=%
```

of course, `paris` will become `par`...

you could try calling a subroutine

```
call :remwi %input%
start www.google.com/maps/place/%result%

...

:remwi
set "result="
:remwiL
for %%a in (where is) do if /i "%~1"=="%%a" goto remwis
set "result=%result% %~1"
:remwis
shift
if "%~1" neq "" goto remwiL
:remLsL
if defined result if "%result:~0,1%"==" " set "result=%result:~1%"&goto remLSL
goto :eof
```

which should remove the words `where` and `is` and return `result`

The two lines after label `:remLsL` should remove leading spaces from `result`.

Comment: Do I have to do something to 'result' so that it will show up when I echo it or so that it will show up when I start google maps?

Comment: The result in `result` would have contained a leading space so the `google maps` invocation would have become (eg) `start www.google.com/maps/place/ paris` because `result` would have contained <kbd>Space</kbd>paris. I've added a little tweak to remove any leading spaces. It should now deal happily with `rio de janiero` for instance - although I've no idea what attempting to run your browser with that data might bring. Possibly you'd need to "encase the entire `start` argument in quotes" - which would mean that an extra pair of rabbits' ears would be required (start "" "http...")

Comment: When I run 'echo %result%' it returns with 'ECHO is off'. Why is that?

Comment: It means that `result` is *nothing* as the resolved instruction is `echo` which reports the `echo` status. You can get over this by using `echo(%result%` which would show *nothing* - well, a new line, or it would show the contents of `result` if `result` actually *contains* a value.